# Android SQLite adding details to database

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi I am fairly new to android development and I am making a simple app that allows a user to enter their details and once the click the 'save' button then their details are saved to the database that I've created. I've created the 'MyDBHandler' class, the 'Details' class with getter and setter methods and the 'MainActivity' class which I'm having the most trouble with. My main problem is that I'm not sure how to insert the data that the user enters into the table I created. My MainActicity class is where I'm lost..can anyone tell/show me what I'm doing wrong. My code is below, thanks.

**MyDBHandler class**

```
package com.example.brian.organdonorapp;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentValues;

public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "detailsDB.db";
public static final String TABLE_DETAILS = "details";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_FIRSTNAME = "firstname";
public static final String COLUMN_SURNAME = "surname";
public static final String COLUMN_PHONE = "phone";
public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
public static final String COLUMN_ADDRESS1 = "address1";
public static final String COLUMN_ADDRESS2 = "address2";

// Pass database information along to superclass
public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_DETAILS + "("
            + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + COLUMN_FIRSTNAME + " TEXT "
            + COLUMN_SURNAME + " TEXT "
            + COLUMN_PHONE + " TEXT "
            + COLUMN_EMAIL + " EMAIL "
            + COLUMN_ADDRESS1 + " TEXT"
            + COLUMN_ADDRESS2 + " TEXT "
            + ");";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_DETAILS);
    onCreate(db);
}

//Add a new row to the database
public void addDetails(Details details){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_FIRSTNAME, details.getFirstname());
    values.put(COLUMN_SURNAME, details.getSurname());
    values.put(COLUMN_PHONE, details.getPhone());
    values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, details.getEmail());
    values.put(COLUMN_ADDRESS1, details.getAddress1());
    values.put(COLUMN_ADDRESS2, details.getAddress2());
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_DETAILS, null, values);
    db.close();
}
}
```

**Details class**

```
package com.example.brian.organdonorapp;


public class Details {
int _id;
String firstname;
String surname;
int phone;
String email;
String address1;
String address2;

// Empty constructor
public Details(String s){
}

public void set_id(int _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

public void setPhone(int phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public void setAddress1(String address1) {
    this.address1 = address1;
}

public void setAddress2(String address2) {
    this.address2 = address2;
}







public int get_id() {
    return _id;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public int getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getAddress1() {
    return address1;
}

public String getAddress2() {
    return address2;
}
}
```

**MainActivity class**

```
package com.example.brian.organdonorapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

TextView firstName;
EditText editTextName;

TextView textView5;
EditText editTextSurname;

TextView textView4;
EditText editTextMobile;

TextView textView2;
EditText editTextEmail;

TextView textView3;
EditText editTextAddress1;

TextView textView6;
EditText editTextAddress2;

MyDBHandler dbHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    firstName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.firstName);
    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    textView5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    editTextSurname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSurname);
    textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    editTextMobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMobile);
    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    editTextAddress1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddress1);
    textView6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    editTextAddress2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddress2);

    dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
    //printDatabase();
}


//Add details to the database
public void addButtonClicked(View view){
    Details details = new Details(editTextName.getText().toString());
    Details details = new Details(editTextSurname.getText().toString());
    Details details = new Details(editTextMobile.getText().toString());
    Details details = new Details(editTextEmail.getText().toString());
    Details details = new Details(editTextAddress1.getText().toString());
    Details details = new Details(editTextAddress2.getText().toString());
    dbHandler.addDetails(details);
    //printDatabase();
}


}
```

Comment: `" TEXT "` -> `" TEXT, "` x5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I think that you shoudl to that :

```
public void addButtonClicked(View view){
    Details details = new Details();
    details.setName(editTextName.getText().toString());
    details.setSurname(editTextSurname.getText().toString());
    details.setMobile(editTextMobile.getText().toString());
    details.setEmail(editTextEmail.getText().toString());
    details.setAddress1(editTextAddress1.getText().toString());
    details.setAddress2(editTextAddress2.getText().toString());
    dbHandler.addDetails(details);
}
```

Also, you can see this tutorial, it will help you.
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: Thank you very much, wasn't sure of how to go about this but now I understand :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating multiple objects of `Details`? You need to create only one instance and set all the values to that object and then add it to the database.

Also the string passed in the constructor of `Details` is never used. So can remove the parameter if you are not planning to use it later.

Do this

```
public void addButtonClicked(View view){
    Details details = new Details("");
    details.setFirstname(editTextName.getText().toString());
    details.setSurname(editTextSurname.getText().toString());
    details.setPhone(editTextMobile.getText().toString());
    details.setEmail(editTextEmail.getText().toString());
    details.setAddress1(editTextAddress1.getText().toString());
    details.setAddress2(editTextAddress2.getText().toString());
    dbHandler.addDetails(details));
    //printDatabase();
}
```